# SQL join with special conditions

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables 1)order_details which stores the order_no and the corresponding details 2)email_details which stores the order_no and corresponding order status update mails.How to get the list of orders for which the delivery mails are not sent?

[image]

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: Fix your data model first. Do **not** store comma separated values in a single column.

Comment: The one that is uploaded is hypothetical table, let's assume I store only one item per order.

Comment: Do you want a hypothetical answer as well?

Comment: The purpose of uploading the image is to just give a basic insight about the problem statement and nothing beyond that, Actually this is related to sterling e-commerce DB tables which are very complex and difficult to provide the complete details.

Comment: I would wonder about your definition of "complexity" when you are asking how to add a where clause to your query...

Comment: @JacobH Sir I am a fresher and just started learning SQL, Please don't discourage me. But thanks for providing your valuable inputs for my question, really appreciate your help!!

Comment: Just pointing out that if you know you are new to SQL then providing more information to us will help you solve your problem better. Omitting data may seem good to "simplify" but in reality it often makes it more difficult to help you. In any case, I hope you got your issue solved!

Comment: @JacobH Yes it really helped me, Thanks again!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that you want the *order_no* for the orders that do not have a *delivery_confirmation* email sent. If that is what you need it will be returned by the following SQL query:

```
select od.order_no 
from order_details od 
left join email_details ed on od.order_no = ed.order_no and ed.sent_emails = 'delivery_confirmation'
where ed.order_no is null;
```

Answer (score 2):

Can be done using a subquery like so:

```
SELECT order_no, itemlist FROM order_details
WHERE order_no NOT IN (SELECT order_no FROM email_details WHERE sent_mails = 'delivery_confirmation')
```

Also, it's bad practice to store your item lists in a CSV format in a column. The strength of a relational database is to avoid that.